Rust function passed in as function parameter vs as generic, performance compare?
Just curious, if there is any runtime performance difference between the implementations as following;
and is there any general guideline for choosing between these two patterns?  thanks;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct SomeStruct;

impl SomeStruct {
    fn add_5(num: u8, get_fn: impl Fn() -> u8) {
        let res = num + get_fn();
        print!("{}", res);
    }
}

fn get_5() -> u8 {
    5
}

trait Get5 {
    fn get_5() -> u8;
}

struct Get5Struct;
impl Get5 for Get5Struct {
    fn get_5() -> u8 {
        5
    }
}

struct GenericStruct<T: Get5>(PhantomData<T>);

impl<T:Get5> GenericStruct<T> {
    fn add_5(num: u8) {
        let res = num + T::get_5();
        print!("{}", res);
    }
}

fn main() {
    SomeStruct::add_5(0, get_5);
    GenericStruct::<Get5Struct>::add_5(0);
}




Sorry for the previous unfunctional code examples, I updated the question with a working compiled code samples;

Check the assembly? :) Also assuming you meant func: fn() -> () and not func: Fn() -> (). Then fn() -> () is not the same as impl Fn() -> (). Since one supports closures that capture and the other is just a function pointer

@vallentin thx, I mean impl Fn()->(), I'll correct it

Since you mean impl Fn() -> () vs F: Fn() -> (), then the answer is that they are basically equivalent. The main difference is how they can be used. For instance with impl Fn() -> (), then you cannot use turbofish to specify a concrete type. While with F: Fn() -> () you can. For closures and functions this is less relevant. But there are corner cases for other types

I just reform the question with new code samples,  and looked at the compiled  assembly code https://godbolt.org/z/xc9xsWGjf  I'm not farmiliar with assembly but it seems they are indifferent; however I'm not sure if it is still the case when code complicates

Exactly, they are identical. So for this exact question with those exact snippets, there's literally no difference. Overall the Rust compiler is pretty clever with optimizations. There's definitely edge cases. But honestly, you're more likely to run into performance penalties from other sources that this. In short, try reading up on what is actually expensive to perform. Instead of just questioning random snippets :)

thanks,  and another thing is pattern using function parameter gives options to passing in functions deternmined in runtime (although with some overhead since the upstream most likely have dynamic dispatch involves in), it's also less verbose to write out;
I guess this is one of the reason that the SerDe deserialize trait chooses to pass in visitor as function parameter;
